# Show user's total login time in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, time

I am working on Bash script, which would show me certain user's sum of times he spent being logged in. I tried using `last mati225 > times1`, then using `cut -d ' ' -f 23- times1 > times2` and `sed '1d;/^$/d' times2 > times1` i got file `times1` with time spent looking like this:

```
(02:32)
(00:27)
(05:33)
```

Now I am thinking of using `cut` to get only hours and only minutes in different files (e.g. `cut -c 2-3 times1 > hours`), then summing them up but there is problem to convert minutes >60 to hours and display everything up. Also it seems to be very complicated way, is there any simpler way to get user's total log time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
last mati225 | awk '$NF ~ /[()]/ {gsub(/[()]/,"",$NF);split($NF,map,":");tot+=(map[1]*60)+map[2]} END { print "Total minutes = "tot }'
```

Take the output of last and then with awk, where the last space separated field contains (), process the line. Remove the ( and ) from the last field (time) and split the field into the array map using ":" as the delimiter. Total the hours * 60 + the minutes into the variable tot. At the end, print the total minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it this way:

```
last mati225|awk '{print $10}'|grep -v in|awk -F'[(:)]' '{h+=$2;m+=$3}END{print h+int(m/60),m%60}'
```